# How to do left join to get all the rows with param?

Tags: sql

I have articles and users tables. I also have another table `articles_users` with FK columns: `userId` `articleId`.

I also have `userId=1`

How to get get all the rows also with extra column that tell me if the userid is linked to this row?

I have try to do this with left join but the problem is `articles_users` have duplicate entries like:

```
 articleId: 1, userId: 1
 articleId: 2, userId: 1
 articleId: 3, userId: 2
```

And it get duplicate articles rows or none.

```
SELECT * FROM articles LEFT JOIN articles_users ON articles_users.articleid = articles.id
WHERE articles_users.userid = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `case` and `exists`:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM articles_users au
                          WHERE au.articleid = a.id AND
                                au.userid = 1
                         )
              THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as flag_1
FROM articles a;
```

Although you can use `JOIN`, I wouldn't recommend it.  If you followed the same pattern for multiple users, you might end up with multiple rows.

Many databases support boolean types explicitly.  In those databases, you can eliminate the `CASE`:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (SELECT 1
        FROM articles_users au
        WHERE au.articleid = a.id AND
              au.userid = 1
        ) as flag_1
FROM articles a;
```